# What is the "unique" keyword in robots.txt?

Tags: robots.txt

I have the following code in robots.txt to allow crawling from everyone for now

```
User-agent: *
Disallow:
```

Before I changed this the layout of the file was this below.  I've been looking for details  about unique and I can't find it.  Anyone see this before and what is "unique" doing exactly?

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /unique/
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a keyword, it's a directory on your server that shouldn't be visited by a web crawler.